# Netezza ODBC Drivers for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, odbc, netezza

I've scoured the internet looking for Netezza ODBC drivers for Mac OS X but I haven't found any. Does anybody know whether or not it exists or where to find it? All of what I've identified were Netezza ODBC drivers for Windows.

Comment: It might be possible with a custom version of SequeLink. Let me know if your want to know more and I'll see what I can dig up.  (http://ow.ly/Auq8y)

Comment: Only if it's free. :)

Comment: Heh, probably not.  ;)

Comment: were you able to find any solution for this @slaw

Comment: No, I haven't. I hear that there is an ODBC driver for Linux but I've been using a JDBC driver on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

IBM does not currently provide Netezza ODBC drivers for OSX clients. From the other answers it sounds like there may be unsupported workarounds thouh.

Answer (score 0):

A few other answers mention unixODBC, however this is not a driver. iODBC and unixODBC are both driver managers, which are essential parts of the ODBC stack that also include an ODBC driver. Having one of iODBC or unixODBC would not alleviate the need to have an ODBC driver as well. It's also worth pointing out that OSX comes with iODBC by default.

Although there doesn't appear to be any first-party Netezza ODBC drivers on OSX, there are other solutions for getting an ODBC driver. One of those solutions is to build your own ODBC driver using something like the SimbaEngine SDK (http://www.simba.com/products/simba-engine-sdk), or having a company like Simba build the driver for you.

You could also petition IBM to release versions of their ODBC drivers on Mac, however you may not have much luck unless you have some money to put behind your request.

Note that in the interests of disclosure, I work for Simba.

Answer (score -1):

For Linux environment UnixOdbc can be used and recommended by IBM to install NZClient. For Mac version details can be found at following link or Source (CPP) files available at site which you can compile and use the binary -

http://danieladeniji.wordpress.com/2012/11/26/unixodbc-on-mac-osx-configuration-files-odbc-ini-odbcinst-ini/

Comment: unixODBC is a driver manager and not a driver, you will need both to make a connection to Netezza. By default, OS X comes with a version of iODBC that you can use, provided you have an acceptable driver.